# How can I repeat a song?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a TMediaPlayer called MediaPlayer1 I then open a file(a song) I play it.
now my problem is that I need the song to repeat until the program stops.

The idea is that the form activates and then repeats the specified song until the form is closed.

```
MediaPlayer1.Filename := 'filename';
```

Then it opens it

```
MediaPlayer1.Open;
```

Then it plays it

```
MediaPlayer1.Play;
```

So now the song is playing but when it ends I want it to play again(repeat) and then again until the form is closed.

I tried what David Heffernan said but it does not work, I think I did something wrong can someone pleas correct me.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, MPlayer, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MediaPlayer1: TMediaPlayer;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MediaPlayer1Notify(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 mediaplayer1.FileName:='E:\it project\mario.mid';
 mediaplayer1.Open;
 mediaplayer1.AutoRewind:=true;
 mediaplayer1.Play;
 mediaplayer1.Notify:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.MediaPlayer1Notify(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if MediaPlayer1.NotifyValue=nvSuccessful then begin
    MediaPlayer1.Play;  
    MediaPlayer1.Notify := True;
  end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: Delphi doesn't have songs. I guess you have some code to play it once. If you want to repeat it, presumably you have worked out how to play it. But you didn't tell us how. We cannot guess. More detail please.

Comment: Sorry its 11pm here where i am and im tired as hell. I edited it hope it makes more sence now

Comment: Your edit is better. I note that you did not have a single upper case character. All your uses of I were "i". And so on. If you want us to care about your problem you should really care about how you ask your question.

Comment: Any idea to how to play a media in loop in FireMonkey as the TMediaPlayer does not have Notify event ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to organise the auto repeat for yourself.

Create an `OnNotify` event for the media player. This fires when the song completes.

```
procedure TForm1.MediaPlayer1Notify(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if MediaPlayer1.NotifyValue=nvSuccessful then begin
    //restart the song
    MediaPlayer1.Play;  
    MediaPlayer1.Notify := True;//ensures we are notified when song completes
  end;
end;
```

The code that starts the song needs to look like this:

```
MediaPlayer1.AutoRewind := True;//for obvious reasons
MediaPlayer1.Play;
MediaPlayer1.Notify := True;//ensures we are notified when song completes
```

Comment: I tried this it did not work though, I think I did something wrong. Pleas check my edit.

Comment: It does work. The code in your question, just like that in my answer works. Probably you forgot to connect the two event handlers up in the IDE. Show us what your .dfm file looks like.

Comment: It's a text file in the same place as your other source files. Did you connect the handlers to the events in the Object Inspector. Also, "it doesn't work" is really unhelpful. Always describe a failure in detail.

Comment: No I did not connect the handlers to the events. Can you maby tell me how to connect them.

Comment: In the object inspector, select the Events tab. In the designer select the appropriate control, i.e. form. Then in the events page of OI, find the event, click drop down, and hook them up.

Comment: I found how to connect them and the song is repeating now!! Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Hi all, i'm using xe8 and seem they've removed the notify event in TMediaPlayer. I'm struggling to do this without this event.

Comment: @thanh Nope, the event is still there as it always was. I guess you are using FMX.

Comment: Yes @david, that's right i'm using FMX, is this property is for VCL form? I'm unable to set the MediaPlayer1.notify := True;

Comment: This question and answer are for VCL

Comment: Thanks @david, i'll find another way to do this in FMX, maybe a timer for it i think

Answer (score -1):

Just use TMediaPlayer: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/MediaPlayer_%28Delphi%29

Comment: i dont think it hasnany repeat function

Comment: So just use the OnNotify event to reply the song (or set of songs) when it ends: http://www.delphipages.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-96813.html

Comment: @paulsm4 That comment should be part of the answer since it's the very crux of the issue at hand.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the OPs question regarding usage of a TMediaPlayer component. You are essentially telling him to use what he's already using.