# Delphi MediaPlayer notification on song stopped

Tags: delphi, notifications

I need to embed a trivial MP3 player in a Delphi7 application. 
I will simply scan a directory and play all the files in a random order.

I found two possible solutions: one using the Delphi MediaPlayer, and one using the PlaySound Windows API.

None are working.

The problem seems to be in the missing "stop" notification.
Using PlaySound like this:

```
playsound(pchar(mp3[r].name), 0, SND_ASYNC or SND_FILENAME);
```

I could not find a way to (politely) ask Windows to inform me when a song stopped playing.

Using the Delphi MediaPlayer, internet is full of suggestions copy/pasted one from the other, like here:

http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=689

http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=44448

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MediaPlayer1.Notify   := True;
  MediaPlayer1.OnNotify := NotifyProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.NotifyProc(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Sender as TMediaPlayer do 
  begin
    case Mode of
      mpStopped: {do something here};
    end;
    //must set to true to enable next-time notification
    Notify := True;
  end;
end;
{
  NOTE that the Notify property resets back to False when a
  notify event is triggered, so inorder for you to recieve
  further notify events, you have to set it back to True as in the code.
  for the MODES available, see the helpfile for MediaPlayer.Mode;
}
```

My problem is that *I do get a NotifyValue == nvSuccessfull* when a song is over but ALSO when I start a song, so I cannot rely on it.
Furthermore, I never, ever receive a change in state of the "mode" property, that should become *mpStopped* according to all the examples I found.

There is a similar question here

[How can I repeat a song?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656296/how-can-i-repeat-a-song)

but it does not work because, as said, I receive the nvSuccessfull twice, without a way to distinguish between the start and the stop.

Last but not least, this app should work from XP to Win10, that's why I am developing with Delphi7 on WinXP.

Thank you and sorry for the length of this post, but I really tried many solutions before asking for help.

Comment: Easiest could be `mciSendString`. You'd create an invisible window (by `AllocateHWnd`) and _listen_ for `MM_MCINOTIFY` message.

Comment: Thank you. In general, programming directly with Windows API is not my "bread&butter" thing, but reading about the MM_MCINOTIFY on MSDN it really looks like it is what Delphi maps onto the "NotifyValue" property, so I guess I will need some more help to distinguish between the two :)

Comment: @Victoria - sounds an interesting solution - but if you are just using the API and not relying on VCL, could you not just use a thread instead? I had the same problem (different application but same problem). Original versions of windows (and I am talking pre XP here) were rock solid in notify mode. Later ones were not. So I am curious about a good solution too.

Comment: @Dsm, yes, using thread and `MCI_WAIT` flag (instead of `MCI_NOTIFY`) is another way. Or having a thread and calling `PlaySound` without the `SND_ASYNC` flag. Another, relatively simple option could be DirectShow API.

Comment: I should really start to delve into Direct* stuff. I am already using it to access the Webcam, so... Time to study :) :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect when to load a new file for playing, you can use the `OnNotify` event and the `EndPos` and `Position` properties of the TMediaPlayer (hereafter called MP)

First setup the MP and select a `TimeFormat`, for example

```
MediaPlayer1.Wait := False;
MediaPlayer1.Notify := True;
MediaPlayer1.TimeFormat := tfFrames;
MediaPlayer1.OnNotify := NotifyProc;
```

When you load a file for playing, set the `EndPos` property

```
MediaPlayer1.FileName := OpenDialog1.Files[NextMedia];
MediaPlayer1.Open;
MediaPlayer1.EndPos := MediaPlayer1.Length;
MediaPlayer1.Play;
```

And the `OnNotify()` procedure

```
procedure TForm1.NotifyProc(Sender: TObject);
var
  mp: TMediaPlayer;
begin
  mp:= Sender as TMediaPlayer;

  if not (mp.NotifyValue = TMPNotifyValues.nvSuccessful) then Exit;

  if mp.Position >= mp.EndPos then
  begin
    // Select next file to play
    NextMedia := (NextMedia + 1) mod OpenDialog1.Files.Count;
    mp.FileName := OpenDialog1.Files[NextMedia];
    mp.Open;
    mp.EndPos := mp.Length;
    mp.Position := 0;
    mp.Play;
    // Set Notify, important
    mp.Notify := True;
  end;
end;
```

Finally a comment to your attempt to use the `MP.Mode = mpStopped` mode to change to a new song. The mode is changed when the buttons are operated, iow `mpStopped` when the user presses the Stop button. Changing the song and starting to play it would likely not be what the user expected.

Comment: Thank you for the solution (that I will try as within 24h) and the explanation of the mpStopped behavior, I was not aware of it. Actually, I am not using the user interface, I keep the control hidden, it was just a simple way to play mp3 files.

Comment: This did not work for me, for some reason mp.EndPos is always 0 (zero). I'm playing a mp3 file

Comment: @delphirules Please be more specific. On which line is `mp.EndPos` zero, when it should not be?